# autodividersSelector of jquery mobile listview not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsrender

I'm trying to use the autodividersSelector option of a jquery-mobile listview as described in the ["Autodividers" section of the List views section of the jquery-mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html).

**The list renders fine, but no dividers whatsoever.** The function assigned to autodividersSelector just never gets called.

There are some other complexities here like jsrender and such, so I'm leaving them intact, but you'll see them below and I don't expect they are part of the problem. What am I missing?

Relevant code below:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myListPage">

    <div data-role="content">   

        <ul id="myListView" 
            data-role="listview"
            data-autodividers="true"
            >

        </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->


<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#myListPage" ).on("pagebeforecreate", function(event) {
    renderTemplates();
});

function renderTemplates() {
    var data = {
        testItems: [
            {name:1},
            {name:2},
            {name:3},
        ]
    };
    $('#myListView').html(
        $('#myTemplate').render(data)
    );
}

/********** FORMATTING **********/
$("#myListPage").on("pagecreate", function (event) {
    console.log("pagecreate");
    $("#myListView").listview({
        autodividers: true,

        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            console.log("autodividersSelector");
            var out = "hi"; //var out = $(li).find("h3").text;
            return out;
        }
    });
    $("#myListView").listview("refresh");
});
/********** FORMATTING **********/

</script>
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

    {{for testItems}}
        <li><a href="#">
         <h3>Name: {{:name}}</h3>
         <p>Test: {{:name}}</p>
        </a></li>
    {{/for}}

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document you linked to is experimental. You are trying to implement something that isn't quite finished yet. Notice how the url says test.

Comment: Ha! I saw test and thought that was strange. Wouldn't hurt for that to be a bit more explicit and listed as "not implemented" or something in the docs. Thank you though!

Comment: Yeah i agree, your the 3rd person i've seen with a similar issue.

Comment: darn! and here is the current 'stable' link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: The newest version (1.2) has Auto-Dividers and they are still a bit rough.